# save_post hook not triggered in WP v3.6.1

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, save-post

I developed a plugin having a custom metabox that is using the `save_post` hook to store data. The plugin is 18 months old and is used by thousands of customers, so I'm pretty sure everything is good.

Since I updated my testing platform to v3.6.1, I can't get that hook to run on previously created pages/posts. It only works on new ones.

(I am the only WP user in the website. WP DEBUG is enabled)

Has anyone experienced the same? Any clue? I missed some changes?

**EDIT:**

The code I'm using now to check the hook is this (I've deleted the inner code for privacy reasons):

```
function saving_metabox($post_id) {
    die('test');

    if(isset($_POST['plugin_noncename'])) {
               ... ...
    }

    return $post_id;
}
add_action('save_post', 'saving_metabox');
```

Comment: Please add the `save_post` hook code that you're using (ie, the function you're trying to run) to your question.

Comment: Sure, I've edited the main post!

Comment: Being an action, there's no need of `return`, only if you want to break further execution. Does that `die()` has any effect? If you disable all other plugins, does the issue persist?

Comment: All the plugins in my testing website have been made by me (except WPML) so I'm quite sure there is nothing wrong.

Anyway I tried deactivating everything and removing the "return" but nothing changes.

This is becoming really really stange..

Comment: I can assure that on WP 3.6.1 `save_post` hook is still triggered. So if you have disabled any other plugin and tested on twentythirteen theme, the wrong code is in your plugin. Try to enable logging (not only debug) and read the log, maybe you'll find some info there.

Comment: Where do you put this code?

Comment: Just under the code to initialize the metaboxes, but it worked and still works for thousands of customers. I faced only two cases experiencing this weird issue

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your content and saving again. This will trigger the action. `save_post` is only called if the content has changed.

To come in before this is checked, you can use the `pre_post_update` hook.

```
add_action( 'pre_post_update', 'saving_metabox' );
function saving_metabox( $post_id ) {
    die('test');
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.